# Passing Data to modal / WebView

Tags: nativescript-vue

In NativeScript-Vue, what's the simple, clean way to pass data to a modal?

Background:
I need to display external web pages in a modal. WebView seems the thing. Except that the [docs](https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/elements/components/web-view/) indicate that you must hard code the source:

`<WebView src="http://nativescript-vue.org/" />`

That's no good. I need something like

```
<WebView :src="myUrl" />

data() {
    return {
         myUrl: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary,_Queen_of_Scots",
}
```

Despite what the documentation says, this seems to work. Yay!!

Now, in the modal, how do I set `myUrl` to a value from the original app page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you original page:

```
this.$showModal(YourWebModal, {
  props: {
    myUrl: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary,_Queen_of_Scots'
  }
})
```

In your modal:

```
<WebView :src="myUrl" />
props: ['myUrl'],
data () {
    return {}
}
```

Comment: Matt, Thank you! Check your parenthesis and brackets. When you correct, i'll mark as answer.

Comment: By the way, I think I had this approach several times, but did not know it because of this bug in NativeScript Playground: https://github.com/NativeScript/playground-feedback/issues/139